# Searching by attribute for special characters (*, ", ')

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

I am working with an attribute table that uses single, double, and triple asterisks to designate Wild and Scenic Rivers.I would like to **Select by Attribute** to filter the records that contain asterisks--I intend to export these records to a separate shapefile just for **Wild and Scenic Rivers**. I tried using the **LIKE** expression as follows, to no avail:

[image: Faulty Code]

Comment: A good way to say thanks is to mark answers as accepted.

Comment: Oops; I'm new here; I was actually looking for a way to do that and I just realized that I need to hit the checkmark!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query is only looking for text with an asterisk with some text after the asterisk.
Try using "ID LIKE'%*%'